# Github actions cache between jobs but not between workflows

Tags: github, sonarqube, github-actions

Currently I am trying to have 1 job scanning SonarQube and 1 job checking for the quality gate in github actions. In order to get the report from gradle of the quality check in the second job, I have to cache it (or atleast with the limited knowledge I have). But I don't want when I rerun the workflow on the same PR or on different PRs use the same cache, since the report is only valid for a current workflow and not futher ones (those need to always create a new report and give the new report to the second job).

Here is my workflow:

```
name: SonarQube
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master # or the name of your main branch
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]
concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true

jobs:
  scan:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0 # Shallow clones should be disabled for a better relevancy of analysis
      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: 11
          distribution: corretto
          cache: gradle
      - name: Build and analyze
        env:
          SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}
          SONAR_HOST_URL: ${{ secrets.SONAR_HOST_URL }}
        run: ./gradlew --info sonar -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_TOKEN
      - name: Cache report
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: build/sonar/
          key: report-task
  qualityCheck:
    needs: scan
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Get cache report
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: build/sonar/
          key: report-task
      - name: Quality Gate check
        id: sonarqube-quality-gate-check
        uses: sonarsource/sonarqube-quality-gate-action@master
        # Force to fail step after specific time.
        timeout-minutes: 5
        with:
          scanMetadataReportFile: build/sonar/report-task.txt
        env:
          SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}
          SONAR_HOST_URL: ${{ secrets.SONAR_HOST_URL }}
```

What needs to be changed to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have currently done this:

```
- name: Cache report
  uses: actions/cache@v3
   with:
    path: build/sonar/
    key: commit-${{ github.sha }}-workflow-${{ github.run_id }}-${{ github.run_number }}-report-task-${{ hashFiles('build/sonar/**') }}
```

This doesn't solve the problem that it keeps the cache after the workflow ends, but it now won't use the report of previous workflows.